# Audio playback in Safari iOS with HTML 5

Tags: jquery, ios, html

I'm having trouble getting the audio tag to play anything on safari for iOS. I'm trying to simply play a file using the audio tag. The following code works on Safari for Mac as well as chrome for android. I am aware of the 'bandwidh conservation' in iOS requiring user interaction to initiate download but I have overcome this by only calling the following code from a click interaction callback. `$("#mySpinner")` is an instance of the `spin.js` (http://fgnass.github.io/spin.js/) library

```
this.audioElement = $('#myAudio');
this.audioElement.empty();

var currentTrack = // .. get the track from backbone model
.......
var source = $('<source></source>', {
    type: 'audio/mpeg',
    src: currentTrack.get('url'),
}).appendTo(this.audioElement);

this.audioElement.appendTo('#container');
console.log("Added the new track to the audio tag");

// $("#myAudio")[0].load();
$("#myAudio").on('canplay', function() {
    $("#myAudio")[0].play();
    $("#mySpinner").hide();
});
```

My own concern lie in the canplay callback; the spinner disappears in chrome but never goes away on Safari for iOS which leads me to believe that canplay may be related. However, according to https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkitjs/htmlmediaelement, this callback is supported.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was a race condition. My solution was to remove all audio elements from the DOM and then repopulate with the url from the `onclick` event.

Like this:

```
        .........
        .........

        // This function modifies the audio tag in order to play the next track
        changeTrack: function() {                
            var currentTrackIndex = this.get('playlistCollection').currentIndex;
            var currentTrack = this.get('playlistTracksCollection').getTrackForIndex(currentTrackIndex - 1); // Indexes aren't 0 based for some reason.....

            // this.changeAudioTrack(currentTrack.get('url'));
            $("#mySpinner").show();
            this.changeAudioTrack(currentTrack.get('url'));
            CSAppConfig.globalAudio.on('canplay', function() {
                $("#mySpinner").hide();
            });
        },

        makeAudio: function() {
            // Create the audio element
            var audio = $('<audio></audio>', {
                id: 'myAudio',
            });
            audio.appendTo($('body'));
            return audio;
        },

        makeAndAppendSource: function(audio, url) {
            // Create the source element
            var source = $('<source></source>', {
                type: 'audio/mpeg',
                src: url
            });
            source.appendTo(audio);
        },

        changeAudioTrack: function(audioURL) {
            // Change the audio track
            CSAppConfig.globalAudio[0].pause();
            CSAppConfig.globalAudio.remove();
            CSAppConfig.globalAudio = this.makeAudio();
            this.makeAndAppendSource(CSAppConfig.globalAudio, audioURL);
            console.log('Calling play');
            CSAppConfig.globalAudio[0].play();
        },

        .........
        .........
```

Answer (score -1):

In iOS, the `canplay` event is unsupported. You just play directly after loading.

Comment: I've just tried `loadeddata` and that also doesn't work

Comment: The proposal that `canplay` is unsupported is untrue; I managed to debug the problem to a race condition. I have tried shutting the spinner on `canplay` and it works on my iPhone 5S running iOS 8